# how can i show my suggestion box in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, intellisense

accidently my code suggestion box [ the box when we start typing it shows us code suggestions ]  is closed and i don't know how... now how can i enable that ??

Comment: You will have to give a liitle mare detail than that, and maybe show some sample code...

Comment: boss when ever we start typing any code snippest in vb.net code editor it shows us a little box continuesly about what should we can do next e.g if we type Di for dim it shows us a list of suggestion with words starting with di i have lost that box how can i re-enable it...

Comment: You are refering to intellisense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

[Modifying IntelliSense Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecfczya1(v=VS.80).aspx)

[enable intellisense visual studio 2008](http://forums.asp.net/t/1472384.aspx)